# Is the DStream return by updateStateByKey function only contains one RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Is the DStream return by updateStateByKey function only contains one RDD? If not,Under what circumstances will the DStream contains more than one RDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the DStream return by updateStateByKey only hava one RDD

Answer (score 2):

It contains a RDD every batch. The DStream returned by updateStateByKey is a "state" DStream. You can still view this DStream as a normal DStream though. For every batch, the RDD is representing the latest state (key-value pairs) according to your update function that you pass in to updateStateByKey.

Comment: Hi, it seemed not like what you said, the code as a part of application bleow only print once every batch, so i think every stateful DStream just have only one RDD

    @transient val statefulDStream = lines.transform(...).map(x => (x, 1)).updateStateByKey(updateFuncs)
    
    statefulDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      println(rdd.first())
    }

Comment: Internally every batch of DStream may point to the same mutable Map that maintains the state of all key-value pairs. I am curious why you need to be concerned about that?

Comment: Thanks again, i want to store all data from input stream into a stateful DStream and want to query sql on the stateful DStream rather then a rdd of the DStream. That is i want to execute a sql query on all data of all batches.

Comment: If the stateful DStream have more than one RDD, when i call statefulDStream.foreachRDD{...} to execute sql on the temp table transformed from rdd of DStream, i count only execute sql on part of all data.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original question. For each batch, there is only one RDD I believe. I think your idea of executing sql on its underlying rdd could work.

Comment: But, as you said, the stateful DStream have more than one rdd, so i could not execute sql query on all data that the stateful DStream contains. I can just execute sql on every rdd of the stateful DStream, thats not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

it seemed not like what you said, the code as a part of application bleow only print once every batch, so i think every stateful DStream just have only one RDD

```
@transient val statefulDStream = lines.transform(...).map(x => (x, 1)).updateStateByKey(updateFuncs)

statefulDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println(rdd.first())
}
```